# JasperReports:Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart, noclassdeffounderror

I am currently working on iReport designer 5.0 for creating charts for my application. I am facing a weird issue where in when Jasper controller calls its own method through controller, it works perfectly fine but when a different service hits MyJasper method we are getting the following exception.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
@Override
public List<JasperPrint> generate_report(HandshakeBeanWrapper handshakeBeanWrapper)
        throws BusinessDataValidationExceptionHandler, JAXBException, SAXException, IOException, JRException {
    CatType catType = handshakeBeanWrapper.getReportType();
    String catLowerCase = String.valueOf(catType).toLowerCase();

    String templatePath1 = getTemplatePath() + catLowerCase + "/";

    String recordPath1 = "/PDF/DashBoardPdfResponse";
    String recordPath2 = "/PDF/DashBoardPdfResponse";
    String recordPath3 = "/PDF/DashBoardPdfResponse";

    String xmlFileName = templatePath1 + catType + XML_NAME;

    String templateName1 = templatePath1 + "FirstPage.jasper";
    String templateName2 = templatePath1 + "Index.jasper";
    String templateName3 = templatePath1 + "Introduction.jasper";

    JRXmlDataSource jrxmlds1 = new JRXmlDataSource(xmlFileName, recordPath1);
    JRXmlDataSource jrxmlds2 = new JRXmlDataSource(xmlFileName, recordPath2);
    JRXmlDataSource jrxmlds3 = new JRXmlDataSource(xmlFileName, recordPath3);

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    File img = new File(getCsatLogo());
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(img);
    parameters.put("logo", fis);
    parameters.put("title", "Piyush Technologies");

    JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(templateName1, parameters, jrxmlds1);
    jrxmlds1.moveFirst();
    JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(templateName2, parameters, jrxmlds2);
    jrxmlds2.moveFirst();
    JasperPrint jasperPrint3 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(templateName3, parameters, jrxmlds3);
    jrxmlds3.moveFirst();

    List<JasperPrint> listt = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
    listt.add(jasperPrint1);
    listt.add(jasperPrint2);
    listt.add(jasperPrint3);

    JRPdfExporter exp = new JRPdfExporter();
    exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, listt);
    exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, destinationFile1);
    exp.exportReport();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return listt;
}
```

Below is the stack trace of the exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart
    at org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.createBarChart(ChartFactory.java:893)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.DefaultChartTheme.createBarChart(DefaultChartTheme.java:741)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.DefaultChartTheme.createChart(DefaultChartTheme.java:276)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.evaluateChart(JRFillChart.java:854)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.evaluateRenderer(JRFillChart.java:819)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillChart.evaluate(JRFillChart.java:808)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:454)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummaryNoLastFooterSamePage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1071)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1032)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRVerticalFiller.java:293)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:129)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:551)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:411)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:122)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:583)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:929)
    at com.cbi.csat.utility.jasper.JasperServiceImpl.generate_NIST_report(JasperServiceImpl.java:320)
```

Comment: Looks like a `CLASSPATH` issue. Please list all the JAR files the application will load from the `CLASSPATH` in the question. Chances are the JAR file for `JFreeChart` is not found.

Comment: Also check for the current version, including the `jcommon` JAR, as suggested [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download.html).